# django foreignkey dropdown redirect to html page

Tags: python, html, django, redirect, django-forms

I'm trying to create a django page that has a single dropdown input, referencing a database with thousands of entries, that when the user selects one of the items and hits "submit", it will redirect them to an html page that generates the stats of the item they chose. I've tried several things and not gotten anything to work, the latest thing I've tried was something I found on here, though I couldn't get it working either, and it is throwing this error at me: "local variable 'team_number' referenced before assignment"

**views.py:**

```
def team_stats(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        team_number = TeamStats(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if team_number.is_valid():
            # do stuff & add to database
            team_number.save()
            team_number = TeamStats.objects.create()
            # use my_file.pk or whatever attribute of FileField your id is
            # based on
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/team-stats/%i/' % team_number.pk)

    return render_to_response('team-stats.html', {
        'team_number': team_number,
    })
```

**forms.py:**

```
class TeamStats(forms.ModelForm):
    model = Team
    fields = 'team_number'
```

**models.py:**

```
class Team(models.Model):
    team_number = models.IntegerField()
    team_notes = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    event_id = models.ForeignKey(
        'Event', on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.team_number)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'teams'
        app_label = 'frcstats'
```

I hope that what I'm asking for help with makes sense. If not, I'll try to explain it better. Thanks

Comment: The problem you're reporting is that you never set `team_number` if the method isn't post, the real problem is probably something else though, could you show your form template please?

Comment: Your view is missing the GET part. The dropdown probably returns a GET request, the POST part is skipped, and then the return statement throws the error - the variable was not defined, since it was GET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a couple things wrong I that I noticed but the one that is causing the issue is that you never set team_number to something if the method isn't post so you shouldn't include this in the context data

I've also changed your view to use the View class instead of a function based view which would allow the view to raise a not allowed response for disallowed requests

```
from django.views.generic import View
class TeamStatsView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, 'team-stats.html',
                      {'team_number': TeamStats()})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        team_number = TeamStats(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if team_number.is_valid():
            # do stuff & add to database
            team_number.save()
            team_number = TeamStats.objects.create()
            # use my_file.pk or whatever attribute of FileField your id is
            # based on
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/team-stats/%i/' % team_number.pk)
        return render(request, 'team-stats.html', {'team_number': team_number })
```

To use this you will have to change the target of your url,

```
 url('your_url_regex', TeamStatsView.as_view(), name='should be here'),
```

I've also changed your code to use `render` instead of `render_to_response` since the latter doesn't use the request and is likely to be removed

---

> The edited version is now throwing an error back "ModelForm has no model class specified."

Thats because the model needs to be set on the meta of the form

```
class TeamStats(forms.ModelForm):    
    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = ['team_number']
```

Comment: So this seems to have worked for the most part, though it's not showing a dropdown menu to select team_number and submit

Comment: @alicen - I've edited my answer to take a guess at what you meant to do.. see the context data in the get method. Its hard to say otherwise how to fix that problem.

Comment: what part doesn't make sense? The edited version is now throwing an error back "ModelForm has no model class specified."

Comment: @alicen - I've updated... if you get any other errors it is probably worth creating a new question if you are unable to resolve the issue

Comment: that solved the error, though the dropdown menu for team_number still doesn't show in the team-stats.html page. Should I just make a new question for that?

Comment: @alicen - Yes ideally, be sure to include what you have tried/researched to try to solve the problem